# ESP32- 200000 lines of CSV data on an SD card. Best way of uploading to Azure SQL database?

Tags: azure, arduino, azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub, esp32

Every 10 mins I capture 200000 lines of CSV data to an SD card on an ESP32 and I need to upload this to an Azure SQL database. Each line of CSV data can be up to about 200 bytes long (so could be 40MB of data).

Right now I'm using Esp32MQTTClient.h to get the data to an Azure IoT Hub, but this seems to have a maximum length limit of about 5500 bytes per message, so I have to iterate over my data about 7000 times to be able to upload it. This works but is far too slow, taking about an hour per 200000 lines.

I was wondering if anyone had any other techniques of uploading larger amounts of CSV data to Azure using the ESP32? The destination has to be an Azure SQL server, but whether or not the data goes via an IoT Hub doesn't really matter.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To upload files with Azure IoT Hub the recommendation is to use File upload functionality. IoT Hub will act as a dispatcher to an associated Azure storage account.

See more here: [Upload files with IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-file-upload)